# Why My android app crashes as soon as I open it in device 4.4.3 but not in device 5.0 or above

Tags: android, android-studio, android-facebook, android-googleapiclient

I have used facebook sdk for log in with facebook and also google map for user current position. It run well in android 5.o or above but crashes in android 4.4.3. I have used following configuration.

```
 android {
             compileSdkVersion 24
             buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

             defaultConfig {
                 applicationId "com.example.nuevo.getsocial"
                 minSdkVersion 15
                 targetSdkVersion 24
                 versionCode 1
                 versionName "1.0"
                 multiDexEnabled true
             }
             buildTypes {
                 release {
                     minifyEnabled false
                     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                 }
             }
             dexOptions{
                 javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
             }
         }
         repositories {
             mavenCentral()
         }

         dependencies {
             compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
             testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
             compile project(path: ':volley')
             compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
             compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
             compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:`enter code here`2.4.0'
             compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
             compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
             compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
             compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
             compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
         }
```

**Logcat is as follow**

> 446/com.example.nuevo.getsocial E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions', referenced from method
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp. 08-29 02:41:35.041
>   1446-1446/com.example.nuevo.getsocial E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zzb', referenced from method
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzcm 08-29 02:41:35.045
>   1446-1446/com.example.nuevo.getsocial E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException', referenced
>   from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getToken 08-29
>   02:41:35.049 1446-1446/com.example.nuevo.getsocial E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$zza', referenced from
>   method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza 08-29 02:41:35.081
>   1446-1446/com.example.nuevo.getsocial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.nuevo.getsocial, PID: 1446
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions at
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
>   at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4309)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Also add Logs from crash.

Comment: Please add crash log

Comment: on 4.4.3 device are you using apk or adb to install the application?

Comment: Please add crash log

Comment: You should add the crash log. Also, I think it's related to the "multiDexEnabled" option you are setting. I think you should add the "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0" library also.

Comment: Check this probably the same issue .http://stackoverflow.com/a/38887728/3111083

Comment: I was facing  similar problem. In my case i was using deprecated functions like `getDrawable()` and `getColor() ` etc. Please see to it whether you are using such methods or not. And please add crash log.

Comment: Why your picasso dependency has `enter code here`?. You supposed to replace that words with 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

replace your appcompat and design libraries into gradle dependencies with following

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Studio User Guide:[Multidex support prior to Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21) use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can use the [multidex support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#multidex), which becomes part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

In your case, if you're supporting old version of Android, you need to include `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0` in your gradle dependency.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for the response.

Comment: You can close this question by mark it as working solution.