# React native app force closes on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, react-native

When I test my React Native app on Android 4.4.2, I get the stack trace at the bottom of this post. This is my build config:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "... my app name ..."
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 30000
        versionName "3.0.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.R$style
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.<clinit>(FacebookSdk.java:87)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5118)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4713)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
05-31 11:20:05.692  5789  5789 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I already tried to add `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0` to my gradle dependencies (mentioned here: [Why My android app crashes as soon as I open it in device 4.4.3 but not in device 5.0 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198823/why-my-android-app-crashes-as-soon-as-i-open-it-in-device-4-4-3-but-not-in-devic)), but that did not help.

Comment: Could you try and align your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`? Set the latter to `23.0.3`

Comment: > The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Comment: Is your project 'app'? That usually occurs when dependencies have a higher version requirement, these are normally lower down in the build.gradle -> e.g. `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"`. If you have any relevant ones try changing them.

Comment: Does not solve it unfortunately... To what do you suggest changing those versions? I also tried to set everything to highest version. It does work on everything android 6+

Comment: This is class not found exception. Have you followed all steps correctly for adding facebook sdk. https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

Comment: I tried it now in debug mode in an emulator... This is more descriptive:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my.appname.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.appname-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.my.appname-1, /system/lib]]`

This is my manifest.xml:

`... package="com.my.appname" ...`

`... android:name=".MainApplication" ...`

Comment: @Gersom did you fix it? i have same issue.