# Error converting byte code to dex:

Tags: android, dex

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCouchbaseLiteCouchbaseLiteAndroid121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCouchbaseLiteCouchbaseLiteAndroidSqliteDefault121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMiguelcatalanMaterialsearchview140Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePlTajchertWaitingdots020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2 mins 52.839 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps on
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.Util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869046/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-okhttp3-internal-util/38887728#38887728)

You have enabled "multiDexEnabled true" and most probably you are not installing it in Application class.

This is how you should do

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true       //You have already did this 
         }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'   // add this in  dependencies
}
```

And finally extend the application

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

And this is a good guide https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 3):

You have several declarations of support library in your gradle.build. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility) is a nice guide how to identify the cause of problem.

Also you can try this easy fix:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```